# Scala: type arguments do not conform to trait Subtractable's type parameter bounds

Tags: scala, loops, collections

I'm new at scala and trying to write function which returns map with all indices for each letter at given string. My code:

```
def group(string: String) = {
  val map = mutable.Map[Char, ListBuffer[Int]]()
  for (i <- string.indices) {
    val ch = string(i)
    if(map.contains(ch)) map(ch) += i
    else map += (ch -> ListBuffer(i))
  }
  map
}
```

When I'm trying to compile I have an error:

> Error:(14, 30) type arguments [?,Iterable[Any] with PartialFunction[Int with Char,Any] with scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[_ >: Int with Char <: AnyVal, Iterable[Any] with PartialFunction[Int with Char,Any] with scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[_ >: Int with Char <: AnyVal, Iterable[Any] with PartialFunction[Int with Char,Any] with scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[_ >: Int with Char <: AnyVal, Equals]]{def seq: Iterable[Any] with PartialFunction[Int with Char,Any]}]{def seq: Iterable[Any] with PartialFunction[Int with Char,Any]{def seq: Iterable[Any] with PartialFunction[Int with Char,Any]}}] do not conform to trait Subtractable's type parameter bounds [A,+Repr <: scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[A,Repr]]
>       val v = for (i <- string.indices) {

It seems that something wrong with value of the loop. So I've added to the last line of loop 'true' and now everything works fine:

```
def group(string: String) = {
  val map = mutable.Map[Char, ListBuffer[Int]]()
  for (i <- string.indices) {
    val ch = string(i)
    if(map.contains(ch)) map(ch) += i
    else map += (ch -> ListBuffer(i))
    true
  }
  map
}
```

What's wrong in my code, and how can I fix it?
Scala version: 2.12.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html

> Scala’s “for comprehensions” are syntactic sugar for composition of multiple operations with foreach, map, flatMap, filter or withFilter. Scala actually translates a for-expression into calls to those methods, so any class providing them, or a subset of them, can be used with for comprehensions.

So, your `for` loop

```
for (i <- string.indices) {
  val ch = string(i)
  if(map.contains(ch)) map(ch) += i
  else map += (ch -> ListBuffer(i))
}
```

equivalent to

```
string.indices.foreach(i => {
  val ch = string(i)
  if(map.contains(ch)) map(ch) += i
  else map += (ch -> ListBuffer(i))
})
```

`foreach` method interface is

```
def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit
```

`map(ch) += i` returns `ListBuffer`, but `map += (ch -> ListBuffer(i))` returns `Map`. And when the compiler tries to identify `U` in `foreach` argument `f: Int => U`, it gets something between `ListBuffer` and `Map` and doesn`t compile it.

Also, the compiler doesn't check result type of if-else expression if you don't use it somewhere.

You can fix your code by rewriting it like this

```
def group(string: String) = {
    val map = mutable.Map[Char, ListBuffer[Int]]()

    def update(i: Int): Unit = {
        val ch = string(i)
        if(map.contains(ch)) map(ch) += i
        else map += (ch -> ListBuffer(i))
    }

    for (i <- string.indices) update(i)
    map
}
```

But better use standard methods

```
def group(string: String) = string.toCharArray.zipWithIndex.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason your method isn't compiling is because you're returning completely different types from your `if-else` expression. One is returning `ListBuffer[Int]`, and the other returns a `Map[Char, ListBuffer[Int]]`.

What you want is:

```
def group(string: String): mutable.Map[Char, ListBuffer[Int]] = {
  val map = mutable.Map[Char, ListBuffer[Int]]()
  for (i <- string.indices) {
    val ch = string(i)
    if (map.contains(ch)) {
      map(ch) += i
      map
    } else map += (ch -> ListBuffer(i))
  }
  map
}
```

An additional approach without a mutable `Map` or `ListBuffer` could be:

```
def group(s: String): Map[Char, Int] = {
  s.split("\\W+")
   .flatten
   .zipWithIndex
   .groupBy { case (char, _) => char }
   .mapValues { arr => arr.map(_._2) }
}
```

Comment: No, I don't want to count occurences of Char in a String. My method works correctly and gives my a proper result. Question is why It doesn't work without 'true' String?

Comment: Is it neccesary to return same types from `if-else`? I can write something like `for (i <- 0 to 10) if (i % 2 == 0) 1 else Array(1)` . `if-else` returns completely different types, but there is no errors here

Comment: @Andrew You can write that, and then the value produced from that expression would be `Any`, and you can't do much with that. No one is forcing your hand to return the same type in such an expression because no return type is expected (more specifically, the compiler is smart enough to figure out the must common supertype of both expressions), while in your `group` method, the contract is expecting a `Map[Char, Int]`, which you aren't satisfying.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you... Where `Map[Char, Int]` is expected? `If-else` returns `ListBuffer[Int]` or `Map[Char, ListBuffer[Int]]`. So the produced value may be `Any`.

Comment: @Andrew The `Map[Char, Int] is only expected in my `group` version, not yours. The way you're using `for` is just syntax sugar over a `foreach`, and the compiler isn't able to infer the return type of the function inside that foreach call.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to keep a ListBuffer for keeping the indexes, we can just update the map entry with a new list of appended index.

```
def group(string: String): mutable.Map[Char, List[Int]] = {

    val map = mutable.Map.empty[Char, List[Int]]

    string.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (char: Char, index: Int) =>
        map += (char -> (index :: map.get(char).getOrElse(List())))
    }

    map
}
```